# Is there a way to send push notifications using Firebase Admin API to all the users of android app?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

As far as I have searched, you can only send notifs by either mentioning registration token of specific user, or group together users by subscribing them to a topic is there a way to send notifications to ALL THE USERS? I want to send the notification from my node backend using the firebase admin api to the android app doing authentication using firebase.

Comment: There is no API to send to all devices with an app. The typical approach is to subscribe the app to a "/announcements" topic on startup and then send to that.